# postgres listen infinite loop in update trigger

Tags: postgresql, loops, triggers, notify, listen

I have a trigger function that simply sends a notification to a channel when something happens, for example when I add a new record into a table. My function code is:

```
create function public.notify()
    returns trigger
    language 'plpgsql'
as $$
begin
    notify "demo_channel";
    return null;
end;
$$;
```

I then create a trigger using the following code:

```
create trigger tr_demo
    after insert
    on public.tb_demo
    for each row
    execute procedure public.notify();
```

Everything works like a charm and everytime a new row is added, my psycopg2 Python script detectes the notification in "real-time" and does something based on that. The issue is that I want my trigger to do the same action when an existing row is updated too, so I changed the second line of my trigger to:

```
after insert or update
```

Unfortunately, if I do this, everytime I ADD a record, the notification goes into an infinite loops, endlessly repeating that action rendering the program useless. Using after insert of delete works just fine.

What's so special about using update in a trigger (ideally I would have an after insert or update or delete clause, to catch any operation on the table) that it makes my code spin out of control? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about UPDATE.  The problem must be coming from the part of your code that you haven't shown us.

For example, if your python code responds to the notification by updating a row in tb_demo, then obviously that update will trigger another notification, which will trigger another update, etc.

Comment: of course... how stupid was I not to realise that I'm updating the status of a row in the very same table every time there's a change. it's a business logic problem now, not a db problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was updating the records in question, triggering an infinite loop up update -> trigger -> update. Fixed.